# Computing additional info internal error in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, error-handling, internal

I have recently downloaded the eclipse mars 4.5 on windows 10. I have been getting an error message any time I am writing code. It is quite annoying,and I was hoping I could get a fix soon.
The error message says:-

`An internal error occurred during: "Computing additional info".
Could not initialize class sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection"`
I am in need of a fix, or a way to disable the part causing the above error.

edits for improvement are welcome.

Comment: i am not so sure, but when i used to work on eclipse every time i got any issue regarding "Computing additional info" i just close eclipse and start it with this command `eclipse -clean -refresh`

Comment: where did you type it?

Comment: if you are using windows then type it in `cmd` after navigating to eclipse path, if in Linux use a terminal (shell)